# How can i know which geopoint(lat/lng) belong to which country without reverse geocoding?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, mapkit, reverse-geocoding

I am making a camping app where i would show on map number of checkins/users to user per country initially, then when map is zoomed, it will show checkins per city in a particular country, when zoomed again, it will show sector wise checkins.

I wanted to ask is there any way to know which lat/lng pair is in which country or city or state without reverse geocoding it? Because if i have 20000 checkins and i reverse geocode each of them, it will take quite long.

What can be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to change the way your data is structured. When a user checks in, besides storing a coordinate, store data such as the city, state, or country associated with the coordinate. Doing it this way, each user would reverse geocode a coordinate before checking in.